# build path either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL

Tags: docker, vue.js, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I tryna figure out docker to run my django rest framework + vue.js project in clouds. I built Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file to start an ubuntu machine and run the postgresql, vue.js and drf containers. But when I try run `docker-compose build` I get the following message:

```
build path either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && upt-get install -y \
    gcc \
    musl-dev \
    node.js \
    postgresql-server-dev-10 \
    apt-utils \
    python3.7 \
    python3.7-dev \
    python3-pip \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN npm install webpack@2.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 8599
      POSTGRES_DB: adserver
    volumes:
      - adserver-data/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
  rest_framework:
    build:
      context: ./app/adserver
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    command: ['python manage.py runserver']
    restart: always
  vue:
    build:
      context: ./app/adserver-vue
    depends_on:
      - rest_framework
    command: ['npm run watch']
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the actual `docker build` command you're running?  What's the actual error you're getting?  What's the first (`FROM`) and last (`CMD`) line in your Dockerfile?  (I have a longer answer about an error in the `command:` overrides in the `docker-compose.yml` file, but I don't think that's your question.)

Comment: The service *postgres* use a image → OK; The service *rest_framework* use the Dockerfile located in `./app/adserver` → OK probably the one you displayed here; The service *vue* use the Dockerfile located in `./app/adserver-vue` → NOK, that one should exists too !

Answer (score 0):

Verify the name of folders because the folder `app/adserver-vue` needs to exist with the name equal in docker-compose.yml